# Given a 1-d numpy array , convert to a 2-d numpy array of desired shape appending 0

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, numpy

I have a numpy array of : x = np.array([5, 6, 7])
I would like to convert it to a 2-D array with a given size. For example lets say the size given is 5, then my resultant array should be :

```
[[0 0 0 0 5]
 [0 0 0 0 6]
 [0 0 0 0 7]]
```

Basically i want to convert the following code of MATLAB to python:

```
tmp = [5 6 7];
B(:,5) = tmp
```

How can this be achieved through numpy.

Comment: You can do that in python, if you first create `B` with `np.zeros`

Comment: I don't know a lot of Python, but it seems [pretty straighforward](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGvNLegUiGxWCGvgKtCwRZI6SUWFSVWakSb6iiY6SiYx2pyVULEq1KL8os1NHJS8zQqNHVMNYES0VY6uoaxQOkKroKizLwSjUrN//8B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your source data are:

```
tmp = [5, 6, 7]  # Source sequence
colNo = 5        # How many columns should have the target array
```

You can get your expected result as:

```
result = np.pad(np.array(tmp)[:, np.newaxis], ((0, 0), (colNo - 1, 0)))
```

`np.array(tmp)` creates a *Numpy* array and `[:, np.newaxis]` converts
it to a **columnar** array.

For further details read documentation concerning *np.pad*.

The result is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB can create a matrix by simply assigning a cell

```
>> B(3) = 1
B = 
   0   0   1
```

and can grow it by assigning more points.  That's really short hand for creating a matrix of the right size and assigning values.  It's convenient, but hides implementation details.

In `numpy` you need to explicitly create the array, and then assign values.

```
In [153]: B = np.zeros((3,5),int)
In [154]: B[:,-1] = [5,6,7]
In [155]: B
Out[155]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7]])
```

If you want a larger array array with more columns, you need to create that, or concatenate this with another array.  There's no automatic array growth.